# Unable to implement image transition in react with styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs

I am still learning how to code and research online was not able to help me solve a css animation problem I am having. I am trying to make an image slide from the left to the right on the click of the button. I will attach an image of the recommendation. [image: 1st screen]

So basically on the click of "dont have an account?sign up" I want the image to transit slowly from left to right then fade so it shows the new screen which is this
[image]

I will post some code to show my components

index.js

```
type Props = {
  setDisplayScreen: Function,
};

const SignIn = ({ setDisplayScreen }: Props) => (
  <ScreenDiv>
    <ImageContainer>
      <ImageDivFemale />
    </ImageContainer>
    <FormDiv>
      <SignInInput placeholder="Username" />
      <SignInInput type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <SignUpButton
        style={{
          cursor: 'pointer',
        }}
      >
        {SIGN_IN}
      </SignUpButton>
      <ForgotUsernameParagraph>
        {FORGOT_USERNAME_PASSWORD}
      </ForgotUsernameParagraph>
      <SignUpParagraph
        style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        onClick={() => setDisplayScreen('SignUpOptions')}
      >
        {NO_ACCOUNT_YET}
      </SignUpParagraph>
    </FormDiv>
  </ScreenDiv>
);

export default SignIn;
```

styles.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import device from '../../config/device';
import PinkButton from '../../components/shared/button-color-pink';
import {
  NunitoItalic18,
  Nunito20,
} from '../../components/shared/nunito/nunito';
import Input from '../../components/shared/Input-field';

const ForgotUsernameParagraph = styled(NunitoItalic18)`
  margin-top: 60px;
  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
`;

const SignUpButton = styled(PinkButton)`
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    width: 82px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 40.2px;
  }
`;

const SignUpParagraph = styled(Nunito20)`
  margin-top: 187px;
  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 45px;
  }
  @media ${device.ipad} {
    margin-top: 10%;
  }
`;

const SignInInput = styled(Input)`
  margin-top: 44px;
  max-width: 600px;
  @media ${device.mobileS} {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  @media ${device.tablet} {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
`;

export { ForgotUsernameParagraph, SignInInput, SignUpButton, SignUpParagraph };
```

Any guidance or help will be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I would toggle a class onto `ImageDivFemale` if the user clicks on `"dont have an account?sign up"`.

The class would have have a `transition` property, a `right` property and an `opacity` property on it.

More about [transitions here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

More about [positions here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

When the condition is false the `resetClass2` could have a `left` transition  on it
to reset back to the original position but this is up to you.

```
<ImageContainer>
  <ImageDivFemale className={currentPage==='SignUpOptions':'transitionsClass1'? 'resetClass2'} />
</ImageContainer>
```

You should set `currentPage` value in the parent component and send it across as props.

Hope you understand what I mean.